# What is the non-recursive sigma notation to describe $k$-th derivative of a polynomial function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation, taylor-expansion

I need to to determine the sigma notation to describe $k$-th derivative of  a polynomial function.

For example if the polynomial function is:
$$
f(x)=a_0+a_1x^1+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4
$$
then then if $k=2$ the $k$-th derivative is:
$$
f''(x)=2a_2+3!a_3x+3\cdot 4a_4x^2
$$

I know there're recursive definitions of $k$-th derivative but I need to determine a non-recursive formula.
In order to generalize the sum of $f^{(k)}$ I came up with this:
$$
f^{(k)}=k!a_k+\sum_{i=k+1\\j=1}^n \frac{i!}{j!}a_ix^j
$$

Is there an established formula for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

notice for $f=ax^n$ we have $f^{(k)}=a\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k}$

you can think of $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ as factorial in the opposite direction, instead of $1\cdot2\cdot\cdots\cdot k$ we have $n\cdot (n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdot\cdots \cdot(n-k+1)$.

now for $f=a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots$ the only thing that changes is $n$, so we get $$f^{(k)}=\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_j\frac{j!}{(j-k)!}x^{j-k}$$

but notice that when $j<k$ we get $\frac{j!}{(j-k)!}=0$, so we can start from $j=k$ to get the final result$$\boxed{f^{(k)}=\sum_{j=k}^{n}a_j\frac{j!}{(j-k)!}x^{j-k}}$$

Answer (score 2):

You basically have the good formula but it is expressed strangely with a mix of $i$ and $j$'s.

$p(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i\,x^i$

$p'(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n ia_i\,x^{i-1}\quad$ we start at $i=1$ since $a_0$ has disappeared.

$p''(x)=\sum\limits_{i=2}^n i(i-1)a_i\,x^{i-2}\quad$ starting at $i=2$.

$p^{(k)}(x)=\sum\limits_{i=k}^n i(i-1)\cdots(i-k+1)a_i\,x^{i-k}\quad$ starting at $i=k$.

We can re-index the sum to have powers of $x$ starting at $0$ (set $j=i-k$)

$\displaystyle p^{(k)}(x)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-k} (j+1)(j+2)\cdots (j+k)a_{j+k}\,x^j=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-k} \dfrac{(j+k)!}{j!}a_{j+k}\,x^j$

Another possibility is to factorize $k!$ to make binomial coefficient appear.

$\displaystyle \dfrac 1{k!}\,p^{(k)}(x)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-k} C_{j+k}^k\,a_{j+k}\,x^j$